# Reason for an RC motor to spin very slowly

Tags: dc-motor

I have the following motor:
[GP307 Ultra Dash Motor by Tamiya](http://www.hlj.com/product/tam15307).

I've read online that you can give this motor up to 16 volts. I have been putting in 11 volts and it spins very slowly, maybe about 200-300 rpm.

I don't know much about how motors work, so I ask you, what would make one of these little motors spin very slowly?

Comment: The website you linked to says it can only handle 2.4-3.0 V

Comment: ok, but would that cause it to spin slow and why?

Comment: I don't know. Where did you find that it can handle 16 volts?

Comment: some nerf gun modding sites.

Comment: What are you using to supply 11 volts?  How much current can it source?

Comment: Did the motor spin faster the very first time you applied 11 volts but now spins much slower?

Comment: yes, maybe it did. i recall when it first turned on i noticed that it sorta stopped, but actually it just started spinning slower. so assuming that happened, can you explain it?

Comment: @jason: 500mamps

Comment: Will it rotate freely with the power off?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the motor is rated for 2.4V to 3V if you are applying 16V you could have cooked something inside since you are at least 5 times rated voltage.

Comment: Probably the motor had many independent coils and one (or some) of them was able to withstand the high voltage; these survivors are bravely trying to spin the motor.